# Using struktex unintentionally changes math font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, packages, struktex

I'm using the `struktogram` environment from the [`struktex`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/struktex/struktex.de.pdf) package to draw structograms in my report. The problem is that the package apparently changes some font definitions, so the formulae in `equation` environments and in math-mode don't match with the text anymore. Changing the position of `\usepackage{struktex}` doesn't help and I couldn't figure out a way to reverse the effect. Please note that I need to use the `scrreprt` class and the font according to the *MWE* provided below. I'm using `pdflatex` to compile the sources.

Here is an example of the **desired result**:
[image: desired]

And here is what it looks like when using `struktex`:
[image: wrong]

- How do I redefine the correct math-fonts after the package is included?
- Is there a way to use the package only locally, so other parts of the document won't be affected?
- Do you have an even better suggestion to achieve the desired result?

---

Here is a minimal working example to reproduce the behavior:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[standard-baselineskips]{cmbright}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{struktex}     % <-- comment out to get the proper math-fonts

\begin{document}

    \section{Structogram}
    \begin{struktogramm}(120,7)
        \assign{A very simple structogram}
    \end{struktogramm}

    \section{Math}
    \begin{equation*} \label{eq:mel_approx_log}
        X(f) = 1234 \cdot \log_{10} \left(1 + \frac{f_s}{2}\right)
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See section 4.1 in the documentation of `struktex`: you have to issue `\MathNormal` if you want to get the “normal” math font.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[standard-baselineskips]{cmbright}

\usepackage{struktex}
\MathNormal % <----------- ADD THIS

\begin{document}

    \section{Structogram}
    \begin{struktogramm}(120,7)
        \assign{A very simple structogram}
    \end{struktogramm}

    \section{Math}
    \begin{equation*} \label{eq:mel_approx_log}
        X(f) = 1234 \cdot \log_{10} \left(1 + \frac{f_s}{2}\right)
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, avoid loading `ae`: it's been obsolete for several years.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. The documentation of `struktex` is not clear on the real effect of `\MathNormal` and its usage to prevent what has happened in my case. A really good finding.